# StringBuilder append and Listbox

Tags: c#

I came across a perculiar problem with StringBuilder and Listbox.
I made a Listbox on a WinForm and called it **lbOut** and a StringBuilder string named **log**.

The code:

```
public partial class formMain : Form
{
 StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
 public formMain()
 {
   InitializeComponent();
   log.AppendLine("This is a test");
   lbOut.Items.Add(log);
   log.AppendLine("Second line");
 }
}
```

If I execute this code, I should get:

> This is a test

Instead I get:

> This is a testSecond line

Why is that?
I mean, "Second line" isn't even add to lbOut.

*I working with Visual Studio 2010, .Net 4.0 on a Vista.*

**Update**: Thanks everyone for the answers. I've learned a bit more today.
I can't vote up (yet), but I was very pleased with the answers given.

I've forgat about the object references

Comment: Because if you append to `log` a second time before you print it, you are still referring to the same object (which has been changed!) when you print it later. I think you didn't show us your whole code though, because if you execute *this* code you wouldn't get anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you pass in the `StringBuilder`, and not the `string`.

Hence, when it is shown in the UI, it calls `ToString` on the `StringBuilder`, which in the meantime has changed it's value.

A possible solution is to pass in the `string`:

```
lbOut.Items.Add(log.ToString());
```

Or, even better, create a `Log` method that logs the string, and adds it to the `ListBox`.

Something like the method below. Note I use `Invoke` if required, so the `Log` method is thread safe:

```
private void Log(string text)
{
    log.AppendLine(text);

    if (lbOut.InvokeRequired)
    {
        lbOut.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            lbOut.Items.Add(text);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        lbOut.Items.Add(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides a hint:

> If the `DisplayMember` property does not have a member specified, the `ListBox` then calls the `ToString` method of the object to obtain the text to display in the list.

The call of `ToString` is not happening right away, when you add the object. It happens only when `ListBox` needs to render the object that you have added. It is the object, not its `string` representation, that `ListBox` keeps. Therefore, every time that you change the object, the text in the `ListBox` is going to change.

If you do not want this to happen, you can add an immutable object, such as a `string`, to your `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

But, you add log to your lbOut. Than you add something to log. It would be weird if it was not changed on your lbOut.

Answer (score 0):

Your listbox has a reference to the `StringBuilder` and after you added it to the listbox you updated the `StringBuilder`. Just use a regular `string` for this.

Answer (score 0):

when you add log to lbOut you are adding a pointer to the object log not the value of log.

you would want to print/log that out before the next append or add the value of log

```
lbOut.Items.Add(log.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the log object to the list. And it gets updated by the second text change. If you want add `log.toString()` to the list, then you should get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing it in the constructor. Internally the CLR sees the 2 log.AppendLine calls both a applied so the value of log is actually "This is a testSecond line".

If you do the exact same code in Form_Load you will get what you expect.